# how to Detect change in Photo asset using ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification when app is running in background

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, alassetslibrary

i used ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification to detect change in photo asset.
it will work fine but the problem is i need to open the app every time to detect the change. How i can do this in background?
here is my code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "assetChange:", name: ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification, object: assetsLibrary)
}

func assetChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    if var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo {   
       if((info.objectForKey(ALAssetLibraryUpdatedAssetsKey)) != nil){
          var set:NSSet = info.objectForKey(ALAssetLibraryUpdatedAssetsKey) as NSSet
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting your code in the AppDelegate.m?

Comment: yes , i put the code in Appdelegate file under this function func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) but it's not work